# Проблема с загрузкой файла на сервер

Tags: c#, .net

метод контроллера

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddProduct([FromBody]AddProduct addProduct, IFormFile file)
    {
        if (file is not {Length: > 0}) return StatusCode(501);
        
        var newFileName = '.' + file.ContentType.Split('/').Last(); 
        var path = "/Images/" + newFileName;
        await using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(_environment.WebRootPath + path))
        {
            await file.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
        }
            
        await _appDbContext.Products.AddAsync(new Product()
        {
            Name = addProduct.Name,
            Description = addProduct.Description,
            ImageSource = String.Format(newFileName, 
                Guid.NewGuid())
        });

        await _appDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

        return Ok();


    }
```

addProduct

```
public class AddProduct
{
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public string? Description { get; set; }
}
```

Возможно проблема в том, что неправильно передаю параметры в postman, если так, то как правильно?
[image: Передача картинки]

[image: Остальные параметры]

Comment: `[FromBody]` -> `[FromForm]`? (и наверно его надо у `IFormFile` задать?)  Ну или поиграйтесь с заголовком `Content-Type` в постмене.

Comment: А ещё в приведённом коде дыра в безопасности.